# I don't want to set permanent path , Java temporary path set using set path command is not working

Tags: java, path, classpath

```
C:\Windows\System32>set path = C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin;

C:\Windows\System32>javac -version
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I don't want to set permanent path I am setting temporary java path so that I can work with different java version but the but the temporary path setting using set path is not working in my computer

Comment: Remove the spaces around the equal sign ...

Comment: I used to have hair. If you want to keep your hair learn this now; `set "PATH=C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin;%PATH%"` is how you do this on Windows. Or, **better**, `set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_202"` and then `set "PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%"` -- because you might want to keep multiple jdk(s).